# /p:VersionSuffix=$(Build.BuildNumber) not working in Azure Devops build

Tags: .net-core, version

I would like to add the BuildId to the Version attribute in my assembly so that I have File Version 1.0.0.1234 for example.

To do this I have added the following to the arguments field of my dotnet build task:

`--configuration $(buildConfiguration) /p:VersionPrefix=$(AssemblyVersion) /p:VersionSuffix=$(Build.BuildId)`

But it doesn't work - when I check the assembly properties it shows the version to be 1.0.0.0

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add the configuration options to my dotnet publish task